# Speeding up mapping creation in ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch

With each index that we create, we need to create mapping for 10 types.

While indexes are created and documents are indexed blazingly fast, bottleneck that we keep hitting is slow mapping creation. In some cases (when we need to create multiple indexes at the same time) it even breaks when ElasticSearch rejects request because mapping was not created in 30 seconds.

Is there any way to speed up mapping creation, or send mappings in bulk?

Comment: I would strongly encourage you to look at [index templates](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-templates.html) if not already done.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I needed!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have to use Index templates, that will allow you to define templates that will automatically be applied to new indices created. The templates include both settings and mappings, and a simple pattern template that controls if the template will be applied to the index created.

More details [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-templates.html).

Regards,
Alain